# Cashing out usdt issue

Tags: usdt

I received some crypto from someone, in Trust Wallet. It is in the format USDT - BEP20.

I tried sending this to a wallet in Binance that was for USDT and on the BEP20 network but nothing came in.

Binance told me their wallet supports "Binance-Peg BSC-USD" but I have "USDT". It seems like the person who sent me the crypto created his own crypto as opposed to actual USDT.

Is there anything I can do to cash this out?

Comment: Could you share the address of the USDT token that you received? If they indeed "created their own crypto as apposed to actual USDT", you're most likely out of luck, as the token they would have created is worthless

Answer (score 1):

> It seems like the person who sent me the crypto created his own crypto as opposed to actual USDT.

It sounds like it to me too. In that case, it's exactly as if the person gave you fake dollar bills he drew and cut himself, they have absolutely no worth and you can't cash them out, unfortunately. If you want, you can give me your address and i'll check for you.

Comment: Is there a way to pm you?

Comment: Discord, it's on my profile

Comment: I've never used discord. How do I get to PM you? I.E. URL etc.

Comment: There's no direct message url feature on discord like there is on telegram or whatever.  You'd have to add me as a friend, just follow https://www.groovypost.com/howto/add-friends-on-discord/

Comment: Can you check now? Alternatively add me, GSS1.